# nodejs connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.206.108:465

Tags: node.js

am trying to send email via nodejs

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'ahmad.s.almasri@gmail.com',
        pass: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
});
```

but i have an error like

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.206.108:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '74.125.206.108',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Is the gmail account setting `Allow less secure apps` set to ON? It could be blocking your app from sending emails using that gmail account.

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: it's already set to On

Comment: are you running the app on a server somewhere? could be a firewall issue...

Comment: it's running in localhost